# How to count values separated by commas in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which was originally a survey where people could answer their dog breeds and their favorit dog breed. Obviously each person can have multiple answers which will be displayed in the same categorie but separated with a comma. However I can't figure out how to count the number of times each breed was mensionned for their respective category.

here is the code:

```
dogs_owned <-c("labrador, golden", "golden","pitbull, chihuahua")
dogs_fav <- c("beagle", "labrador, shepherd", "chihuahua, pitbull")
test <- data.frame(dogs_owned,dogs_fav)

list <- c("labrador", "golden","pitbull","chihuahua","beagle","shepherd")
list_test <- data.frame(list)
list_test$count_own <- 0
list_test$count_fav <- 0
```

The goal is to count how many times the name of each breed of dog appear in either dogs_owned and dogs_fav in their respective list count

Comment: Try: `table(unlist(test))`

Comment: @zx8754, note there are strings such as `"chihuahua, pitbull"` where they need to be split

Comment: @r2evans yeah, hence it was a comment, but the idea is using table.

Comment: it lists objects such as "labrador, golden" as only one. What I wanted to do was to separate "labrador" from "golden" to count them separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
out <- Reduce(function(a, b) merge(a, b, by="Var1", all=TRUE),
  lapply(test,
    function(z) as.data.frame.table(table(unlist(strsplit(z, "[ ,]+"))), 
                                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))
names(out)[-1] <- names(test)
out
#        Var1 dogs_owned dogs_fav
# 1    beagle         NA        1
# 2 chihuahua          1        1
# 3    golden          2       NA
# 4  labrador          1        1
# 5   pitbull          1        1
# 6  shepherd         NA        1
```

Brief walk-through:

- `strsplit(z, "[ ,]+")` splits a string by consecutive commas and spaces (this is a trick to remove the need for `trimws`, which also works well); this results in

  ```r
  strsplit(test$dogs_fav, "[ ,]+")
  # [[1]]
  # [1] "beagle"
  # [[2]]
  # [1] "labrador" "shepherd"
  # [[3]]
  # [1] "chihuahua" "pitbull"
  ```
- `table(unlist(.))` converts that to a vector and counts them

  ```r
  table(unlist(strsplit(test$dogs_fav, "[ ,]+")))
  #    beagle chihuahua  labrador   pitbull  shepherd 
  #         1         1         1         1         1
  ```
- `as.data.frame.table(.)` converts that to a 2-column frame with names `Var1` and `Freq`
- `merge(a, b, by="Var1", ...)` combines the 2-column frames by the `Var1` column (dog type), keeping each `Freq` column unique. Using `all=TRUE` ensures dogs found in one and not another are preserved
- `Reduce` allows us to do this for a dynamic number of columns, so if we had more `dogs_*` columns, this same code works unchanged

Comment: I like the function as it puts the results back into a dataframe. Quick question what is `names(out)[-1]` doing? Also, an explanation for the functions being used in `out` would also be helpful, thank you.

Comment: The default behavior of `as.data.frame.table` is to name the two columns `Var1` and `Freq`. After `Reduce`, the column names are `Var1, Freq.x, Freq.y`, and if there are more than two such `dogs_*` columns, there would be more `.x`-ification. The `names(out)[-1]` is meant to bring the `dogs_*` names back in dynamically (and not replacing the first, though changing `Var1` to something else might be desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strsplit` to split strings and then count them using `table`

```
> (owned <- as.data.frame(table(trimws(unlist(strsplit(test$dogs_owned, split=","))))))
       Var1 Freq
1 chihuahua    1
2    golden    2
3  labrador    1
4   pitbull    1
> (fav <- as.data.frame(table(trimws(unlist(strsplit(test$dogs_fav, split=","))))))
       Var1 Freq
1    beagle    1
2 chihuahua    1
3  labrador    1
4   pitbull    1
5  shepherd    1
```

If you wish them in one data.frame, we can use `full_join` from dplyr package as alternative to `merge` (see r2evans' answer)

```
> library(dplyr)
 owned %>% 
   full_join(fav, by="Var1") %>% 
   rename(Owned = Freq.x,
          Fav = Freq.y)
       Var1 Owned Fav
1 chihuahua     1   1
2    golden     2  NA
3  labrador     1   1
4   pitbull     1   1
5    beagle    NA   1
6  shepherd    NA   1
```

Comment: How would you then put these results back in a new `df`?